# What it is the error in this ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

perhaps this could be extremely simple, I can't find why this ajax call is not working. I put the post call equivalent that works.

```
    //this works
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ingresa_usuario_form').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('action');
            var datos = $(this).serialize();
            $.post(url, datos, function (resultado) {
                $('#posted_values').html(resultado);
            });
        });
    });

    //this doesn't work
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#ingresa_usuario_form').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: "text/plain",
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#posted_values').html(response);
                }
            });
        })
    });
```

Comment: Why did you set the `dataType: "text/plain"` parameter? Also when you say that it doesn't work it's as if you said nothing. What do you see in FireBug? What's the server response? Is the AJAX request being sent? Guys please learn to debug your code and stop saying `it doesn't work`. It's so annoying. Especially when you have tools such as FireBug, Chrome Developer Toolbar and Fiddler nowadays it's blasphemy that a web developer says `it doesn't work` without providing some real details.

Comment: Looks good to me. Is the request being sent?

Comment: Thanks @DarinDimitrov, your first question put me in the right direction. I put "text/plain" instead of "text". This question I think could be deleted, I was desperate to find an answer because it was so simple and I couldn't see it, and is really a poor question... I'm going to put a delete vote.

Comment: You don't need to be putting any delete vote but just click on the `delete` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your url does not accept the contentType "text/plain", and only accepts the default contentType of $.post which is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8". Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

As from [$.ajax tutorial](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) `dataType` can only be `xml`, `json`, `script` or `html`. But more information needed on what is "this doesn't work".